# Dynamically populate multiple check-boxes and store checked values to one model field in form in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I'm creating mvc application.In the database I have one table for user groups , another table to product fields.

I created form to add new product fields.When I add new product field I want to Assign User Groups(These user groups can dynamically change).I want to do this using check boxes like below picture

[image]

this is product fields model class

```
public partial class ProductField
{
    public string ProductFieldID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeAr { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldDiscriptionAr { get; set; }
    public string UserGroup { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

this is view page

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductFieldID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFieldID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductFieldID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameAr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductFieldNameAr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductFieldDiscriptionAr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductFieldDiscriptionAr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductFieldDiscriptionAr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I checked User groups those valuse should be store under one field in Product field table (which is "User_Group" nvarchar field)

is this possible ? Really appreciate can suggest a way to achieve this

Comment: What is the html your generating for the checkboxes?

Comment: cshtml view pages I'm using

Comment: No I mean show the view!

Comment: I want load those check-boxes from user groups and store checked valuse to one field in "product fields" table

Comment: updated code just look at

Comment: There is nothing in your edit relating to any checkboxes (what you have show is not relevant to the question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85261/discussion-between-chathz-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

For each one of your checkboxes add corresponding model property and make `UserGroup` claculated field

```
public partial class ProductField
{
    public string ProductFieldID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeAr { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameAr { get; set; }
    public string ProdcutFieldDiscriptionEn { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldDiscriptionAr { get; set; }
    public string UserGroupSerialized { 
       get
       { 
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserGroups, Formatting.Indented);
       }
    }

    public IList<KeyValuePair<string,bool>> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@for(var i=0; i<UserGroups.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("", Model.UserGroups[i].Key , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserGroups[i].Key)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserGroups[i].Value , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })                
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: but these user groups can dynamically change . then how can I handle it ? that means new user groups can be add and current user groups may delete. I want to retrieve all those existing user groups from "user groups" table and list it under create new product field form.

Comment: What do you mean by 'groups can dynamically change'. Are the changed by user through an application ? Are the changed by developer?

Comment: No there is another form for add new user group , after I created a new user group that one also list down under product fields form "Viewer user groups" section

Comment: Take a look at the updated version. Here I used a  `IList<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>` to hold a dynamic collection of user groups. UserGroupSerialized simply serializes this collection into a JSON so you could store it in the DB

Comment: Thnk you very much ,  In your code where those user groups extract from ?

Comment: You need to populate your model. I assume that you are going to populate it from DB. Just get all available user groups from DB and for each one of them create `KeyValuePair<string,bool>` and add it to `UserGroups` property

Comment: `'AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.UserGroupSerialized.get': not all code paths return a value` getting this error in ProductField model class

Comment: of course you need a return statement inside get (code updated)

Comment: actually I don't have that much knowledge, really appreciate your help. `The name 'UserGroups' does not exist in the current context` getting this error in view page